# Is there a way to have a function return a generic Action, with a variable number of parameters?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I have a scenario in which the best solution seems to be to have a certain area of my code determine possible behaviours, and return the appropriate one to the rest of the code, based on certain conditions.

Something like:

```
Action<int> foo = (int a) => a + 1;
Action<int, string> bar = (int a, string b) => b + " : " + a;

private Action GetTheRightAction(bool condition)
{
  if (condition)
     return foo;
  else
    return bar;
}
```

The real code is obviously more complex, and `foo` and `bar` have a closer relationship in behaviour to one another.
The general idea persists, though. Is there a way for `GetTheRightAction` to have a generic return type?

Comment: No, you'd need lots of overloads, though I'm guessing that you're looking at this the wrong way. Without knowing more about your structure, perhaps some sort of composition pattern might remove the need for actions altogether.

Comment: How would you know how to call the result of this function? `var action = GetTheRightAction(condition);` now what?

Comment: If the method has a generic argument it can have a generic return type. `Action<T> GetTheRightAction<T>(bool condition)`. That implies that when you call `GetTheRightAction` you already know what you want arguments you want it to have. Very generally speaking, when we're trying to write code where one method can return all sorts of different types and we don't know what type we expect it to return when we call it, something is wrong.

Comment: Sounds like `GetTheRightAction` should actually named `DoTheRightAction` as part of an interface between two concrete classes.

Answer (score -3):

While I appreciate the comments about the potential pitfalls of this approach, I do believe this is the right solution for this particular problem.

For general reference, I was able to get this working with a code similar to what's shown below.

```
public delegate void MyFunction(params object[] arguments);
MyFunction foo = (object[] arguments) => // check for arguments length and types here to direct the appropriate behaviour
MyFunc GetTheRightAction(bool condition) => // return between different MyFunc implementations as needed
```

Is not as clean as I was hoping for, but it does the trick.

Comment: Note that you are getting downvotes because this is a really bad way to implement this.

Comment: While I realize that,  I'd appreciate if those downvotes also came with arguments. (ie. this solution leads to problems X, Y).
Ultimately, I'm the only one who knows the context of the problem I need to solve, and I don't take architectural decisions lightly.
While C# doesn't lend itself so well to Functional Programming, adhering to the standard and creating tons of interfaces/composition just because it's "how we usually do in C#" is not a strong enough argument to compel me.
What I'd truly appreciate is some technical rationale of why this approach is a bad one.

Comment: People commenting on their downvotes is so often met with hostility that it doesn't happen often. I haven't downvoted you, but I would say it's a terrible idea for various reasons, not least is that you have lost all compile-time type checking. You wouldn't do something like this in a functional language and you shoulnd't do it in C# either.